# How does copy constructor that returns value, discards the temp?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvalue

having this code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;

    explicit Base(int val) : _var(val) {}

    Base operator=(const Base &rhs) {
        _var = rhs._var;
        return *this;
    }

    void print() const {
        std::cout << _var << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int _var;
};

int main() {
    Base b[] = {Base(10), Base(), Base(), Base()};
    (b[1] = b[2]) = b[0];
    for (Base base: b) {
        base.print();
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
10
0
0
0
```

but I would expect

```
10
10
0
0
```

As the second element in array `b[1]` should get assign from `b[0]`, but the assignment operator returns value, not reference and thus copy-constructing happen. But still, why is not `b[1]` copy-constructed to have `_var=10`?

If the `operator=` returned `Base &`, the output would be my expectation

Comment: With parentheses you specified that `b[1] = b[2]` will happen first no matter what. What's `var` of `b[2]`? It's 0

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov but then the `b[1]` should get assign var of `b[0]`, which is 10

Comment: No, `b[1] = b[2]` returns a copy of `b[1]` here, check the return type of your assignment operator (it's not a reference type). So `b[0]` is being assigned to a copy of `b[1]` that is then being discarded.

Comment: Why so? `b[1] = b[2]` returns by value, so it's a temporary copy of `b[1]` get's assigned to `b[0]`. Since you don't save this copy, it's just discarded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired result of your *assignment operator* (which, by the way, is different from *copy constructor*), you need to return a reference:

```
Base& operator=(const Base &rhs)
```

This is the canonical form.

Without the reference, the result of `(b[1] = b[2])` is stored in a temporary. `(b[1] = b[2]) = b[0];` assigns to that temporary, which is discarded and has no effect on `b[1]`.

Comment: But how can you even assign to temporary (ala rvalue)? That should not be possible, otherwise you could do things like `6 = 5` and both operands are rvalue. So why the `operator=` which returns value even compiles?

Comment: C++ does not allow assigning to built-in rvalue, but allows it for user-defined types.

Comment: I don't get it. Rvalue is always rvalue, whether as primitive, built-in type or user-defined. Why are there exceptions?

Comment: @milanHrabos • Ahh, what you are expecting is `Base operator=(const Base &rhs) && {...` but since you didn't qualify it with the `&&` on the end you got both.